# Eclipse Crashes automatically after some time

Tags: java, ubuntu, jboss, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse as development IDE for our java project. Unfortunately the IDE is crashes means it closing frequently after working some time on it. I goggled to find the root cause and find the some sort of solutions but those were not worth to resolve it.
So anybody please help me to resolve this as early as possible.

Following the platform specifications i am using for development environment.

**Eclipse**
      Version : Indigo Service Release 1
      Build id: 20110916-0149

**Ubuntu**
      Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
      Description:  Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)
      Release:  14.04
      Codename: trusty

**Java**
     jdk1.7.0_13

**Jboss**

```
 JbossAs 7.1.1
```

Thank You In Advance

Regards,
KISHORE

Comment: Is there any Error message you can share?

Comment: same for me, using SpringSourceToolSuite 3.5.1, no dump created.
All was working fine with ubuntu 13.10 :(